# Typescript: When is a type spreadable?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having trouble using object spread in ***Typescript*** functions with Type variables.

*Is it possible at all (as of now)? If not, what are concise alternatives?*

Here is what I observed with both **Typescript v2.6 and v2.7-dev**: 
In the function definitions below, the `ok` ones compile just fine but the `err` ones give the following compiler error:

> TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.

```
interface IMessages {
  [msgKey: string]: string; 
}

const ok1 = () => {
  type TFieldNames = "a" | "b" | "c";
  const fieldErrors: { [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages } = {};
  const fieldName = "XXX" as TFieldNames;
  const otherMessages = fieldErrors[fieldName]; // has type IMessages
  fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};

const ok2 = () => {
  type TFieldNames = keyof { a: number; b: number; c: number };
  const fieldErrors: { [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages } = {};
  const fieldName = "XXX" as TFieldNames;
  const otherMessages = fieldErrors[fieldName]; // has type IMessages
  fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};

const ok3 = () => {
  type TFieldNames = string;
  const fieldErrors: { [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages } = {};
  const fieldName = "XXX" as TFieldNames;
  const otherMessages = fieldErrors[fieldName]; // has type "any"
  fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};

const err1 = <TFieldNames extends string>() => {
  const fieldErrors: { [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages } = {};
  const fieldName = "XXX" as TFieldNames;
  const otherMessages = fieldErrors[fieldName]; // has type "any"
  fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};

const err2 = <TFields extends { [key: string]: any }>() => {
  const fieldErrors: { [field in keyof TFields]?: IMessages } = {};
  const fieldName = "XXX" as keyof TFields;
  const otherMessages = fieldErrors[fieldName]; // has type "any"
  fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};

const err3 = <TFields extends object>() => {
  const fieldErrors: { [field in keyof TFields]?: IMessages } = {};
  const fieldName = "XXX" as keyof TFields;
  const otherMessages = fieldErrors[fieldName]; // has type "any"
  fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};
```

Comment: The indexed property definition `[field in ...]` is confusing because `in` operator returns a boolean. To limit a string value inside a list of values, we can write something like `[field: keyof TFields]` or `type Keys = 'a' | 'b';` and `[key: Keys]`. But these patterns are not supported for an indexed property.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between an **indexed type** à la `[field: string]` and a so-called **mapped type** `[field in T]: U` (See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). The latter implies that *all* the properties of T are present in the new type. (When you add a question mark like `[field in T]?: U` that makes all properties optional.) Not sure what other differences are and whether they are by design...

Comment: Thanks :) I've been confusing both, not having notice the syntax difference. I understand now why it's not possible to write `{ [key: keyof X]: X[key] }`, since it's a mapped type à la `{ [key in keyof X]: X[key] }` I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the inferred type in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) for `otherMessages` in `err1`, it's

```
const otherMessages: { [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages; }[TFieldNames]
```

And it starts working if you add explicit type for `otherMessages`:

```
const err1b = <TFieldNames extends string>() => {
    const fieldErrors: { [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages } = {};
    const fieldName = "XXX" as TFieldNames;
    const otherMessages: IMessages | undefined = fieldErrors[fieldName]; 
    fieldErrors[fieldName] = { ...otherMessages, too_big: "is too big" };
};
```

It seems that typescript on its own is unable to simplify `{ [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages; }[TFieldNames]` to `IMessages | undefined`. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I wonder why Typescript can't simplify that, can't see a good reason. Probably a bug, yes. And my IDE was even dumber :) – Hence thanks for sharing the link to the playground, too.

Answer (score 0):

To complement artem's answer: this interface is not a valid in the Playground :

```js
interface MessagesMap<TFieldNames extends string> {
  [field in TFieldNames]?: IMessages; // TsError: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol' or 'any'
}
```

So, `err1` function should not compiled from the beginning.

If you need an object with string-indexed properties, this TypeScript constraint encourages us to simplify the design and to prefer using a simple `string` type instead of a more precise type using generic and `keyof` or `in` operators:

```js
interface FieldMessages {
  [field: string]: IMessages;
}
```

Or use a `Map<K extends string, IMessages>` object.

Comment: Yet it does compile. That's because `fieldErrors`'s type does not have to be an interface. It can be any type. If you change `MessagesMap` to be a `type` instead of an `interface`, the error will go away. If you find out why that's the case, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting an issue :)